# How to add option correctly in `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" start`

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

To avoid `[ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'` I need `[ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'`. 
But `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf"` gives me `[ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!`.
And I learned that I need `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld start` to start the service. But `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" start` gives me same error as `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf"` and `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld start --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf"` is same as `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld start`... So I don't know what to do...

PS: In `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --verbose --help`, it mentioned that `--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.`